# Python code not storing readings in a .csv file. "sequence expected" error recieved. Any idea how to fix this?

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi, gps, syntax-error

I was applying a code that reads the coordinates from a gps and fills it in a .csv file.i am new to all of this so i can't get my head around this problem. I have used the "csv" code in other programs and it has worked. But here it is giving me a hard time. The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GPScodetest2.py", line 48, in <module>
   data_writer.writerow(data)
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

How to fix this?

P.S the code:

```
from time import sleep, strftime, time
import serial
import pynmea2
import datetime
from csv import writer



#setup the serial port to which gps is connected 
port = "/dev/ttyS0"
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 0.5)
dataout  = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
counter = 0



def get_sense_data():
        while True:
               newdata = ser.readline()
                  if newdata[0:6] == '$GPGGA':

                       parsed_line = pynmea2.parse(newdata)

                       latitude_reading = parsed_line.latitude
                       alpha = latitude_reading

                       #print(newlat)
                       longitude_reading = parsed_line.longitude
                       beta = longitude_reading

                       #print(newlong)
                       #print(latitude_reading)
                       #print(longitude_reading)

                       sense_data=[]
                       sense_data.append(counter)
                       sense_data.append(datetime.datetime.now())
                       sense_data.append(alpha)
                       sense_data.append(beta)

                       return sense_data

with open('GPSdata.csv', 'w+') as f:
        data_writer = writer(f)
        data_writer.writerow(['Term No.','Date and Time','Latitude', 
 '      Longitude'])
        while True:
               data = get_sense_data
               data_writer.writerow(data)
               counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: There appears to be indentation problem with your code, right when it goes into the `white True:` it adds 2 levels of indentation

Comment: @VaibhavSharma tried to fix that too, didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling the function:

```
data = get_sense_data
```

Try calling it:

```
data = get_sense_data()
```

Comment: It fixed the sequence issue but now there is a csv file with NO data in it.  not even the headers

Comment: I suspect that providing the full absolute path to the file will help that: `with open('/full/path/here/GPSdata.csv', 'w+') as f:`

Comment: @AjdarAneeqMalik if this fixed your sequence issue, please feel free to accept this answer